# Python couldn't insert row to MySQL

Tags: python, mysql, sql

I'm trying to accomplish following query:

```
sql = "INSERT INTO adr_citydistricts (CityDistrict, CityDistrictRU) VALUES (% (ua) s,% (ru) s);"
data = {'ua': 'ukrainian', 'ru': 'russian'}
cursor.execute (sql, data)
```

After executing this query, there is no such record in table.

If do the same query in SQLyog, record will exists.

I've also tried:

```
sql = "INSERT INTO adr_citydistricts (CityDistrict, CityDistrictRU) VALUES ('123 ', '333');"
cursor.execute (sql)
print sql
```

and there is no row in the table.

The console displays : `INSERT INTO adr_citydistricts (CityDistrict, CityDistrictRU) VALUES ('123 ', '333');`

Executing this query in SQLyog, normally inserts a row in the table.

I've created another table with the same structure.

Can someone help me, please?

Comment: 'osuschastvlyaetsya' - hah. Is it translated word from google? For finish sql transaction, you need to commit it.

Comment: @AntonBarycheuski in case you understand what that word mean, would you mind editing the question and translating it in English? Thanks.

Comment: @StefanoSanfilippo, Ok. I have correct it and rephrase some items.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to [`cursor.commit()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlconnection-commit.html) to reflect changes.

> #### [9.2.3. Method `MySQLConnection.commit()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlconnection-commit.html)
>
> This method sends a COMMIT statement to the MySQL server, committing
> the current transaction. Since by default Connector/Python does not
> autocommit, it is important to call this method after every
> transaction that modifies data for tables that use transactional
> storage engines.

Comment: db = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost",user="root", passwd="*****", db="test", charset='utf8')

cursor = db.cursor()

sql = "INSERT INTO adr_citydistricts (CityDistrict, CityDistrictRU) VALUES ('123', '333');"

cursor.execute(sql)

db.commit()